# listview doesn't scroll up until i touch it

Tags: android, listview, scroll

i have a `listView` and a `button` ...
when i scroll down on the list .. the button which i named 'scroll_up' appears, so when i click it the list should scroll to the top.. but it didn't until i touch it.. i mean after clicking the button nothing happens ..but if i touch the list it scoll to the top ..

here is my button onClick

```
public void scrollup(View v){
   lv.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
}
```

there is no error in the logcat...
Note:I use a header in the list .. maybe this what cause the problem ..
so is there a way to refresh the layout or somthing similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move to first index of the list view, use below code:

```
listView.setSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to smooth scroll you may add line in listview in xml

```
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
```

or in code:

```
lv.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
```

And after your code

```
lv.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```